# WordPress - How to track themes folder only from git repository

Tags: wordpress, git

I have duplicated a WordPress site to my local machine, so that I can work and maintain it. Now assume that someone else has created a custom theme and created a git repository and pushed that custom theme (only the themes folder), so that I can integrate it into my WordPress intallation. How can I sync that theme folder to my WordPress installation?

Do I have to:

```
- git init
- git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git.
```

or am I wrong? how do I only track the themes folder?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Are you trying to do this somehow with PHP? Why the PHP tag?

Comment: @j08691 sorry, since wordpress is php I guess I included it... Did remove it

Comment: Why aren't you both working on the same repo?